# AutoScrolling on Slider Gallery

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have this example of gallery, and i'm new on jQuery. I want to know, if theres a way to implement an autoscrolling of this images....

http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/SliderGallery/

Comment: depends what you mean by _autoscrolling_...

Comment: As you can see on the site, you need to click on buttons to move the images. I wish that the images were moving for example every 3 seconds without the need to click the arrows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

lets say you have functions `next()` and `prev()` to scroll the images with the buttons.  if you want to *autoscroll*, based on what you've written above, you would use a timer via the `setTimeout` function like so:

`window.setTimeout(next, 5000);`

This would scroll to the next image every 5 seconds.  Now, if you're at the end of the gallery, you could write some logic to determine that and go back to the beginning or go in the reverse order.

*However, Because there can be a logic involved in something like this, I would highly recommend using a third-party jQuery plug-in such as [Nivo Slider](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CCMQFjAA&url=http://nivo.dev7studios.com/&ei=QcDbTafzM8Tq0gHhzsDRDw&usg=AFQjCNHQ92TUOrA92_w2UR6SFHFLNjFd6Q)...*

Comment: ok i understand, now i need to find a way to merge this with this gallery, i think i need implement this on openGallery function, because this opens a gallery after cliking on a city on that example...